# Plot a 'Power Triangle' in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot the 'power triangle' in *Mathematica*, is there a way to do it?

Exactly the way it is presented in this [**picture from here**](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/ind83.gif?81223b):

[image]

But I've to can change the values in the triangle

---

As far as I got know:

```
Show[Graphics[{FaceForm[
    RGBColor[0.5866666666666667, 2/3, 0.5866666666666667]], 
    Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]}], 
    PlotLabel -> HoldForm[Vermogensdriehoek], 
    LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]
```

---

I'm stuck here, my axes has to be a arrow and I've to get the text in the right place, any help?

(Vermogensdriehoek is Dutch for Power Triangle)

Comment: Is there any particular reason to think there *isn't* a way to do this? I mean, what about it has given you problems, specifically?

Comment: They (someone I am working with) asked me to make it in Mathematica and I've no idea how to deal with it, that's why I decide to ask it here

Comment: Please understand that this isn't a code-it-for-me service!

Comment: Hints are also welcome, bro ;) I hope I am not offending you, if I did I'm sorry

Comment: No offense. This site is aimed at those trying to learn Mathematica or users having troubles with their code. But that needs a previous code, not a blank page and zero knowledge because Mathematica is a pretty complicated beast

Comment: well, I guess the "zero knowledge" was impolite. Now _I_ am  sorry :)

Comment: It is oke, but as I said hints are also welcome, I've no idea how to start so thats why

Comment: Look at the documentation for `Graphics` and maybe try to follow the examples there. I find the graphics primitives `Polygon`, `Line`, `Text`, `Circle`, and `Arrow` particularly useful. `Graphics` allows you to draw pictures using math, basically.

Comment: I already did, but they didn't give me what I want

Comment: The point is not to find your exact picture there. The point is to use the documentation to figure out how to do it. In addition, there are lots of MMA graphics tutorials online, and if you scroll to the bottom of the `Graphics` help page, there are more links to more information.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find, give me link to any tutorials

Comment: At least http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Polygon.html and http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphicsDirectives.html

Comment: Check out MathWorld [Triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/search/?query=Triangle&x=14&y=12) and [A triangle is a 3-sided polygon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Triangle.html) and http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/, see [Triangle](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=triangle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Manipulate[
 Graphics[
 {FaceForm[RGBColor[0.587, 2/3, 0.587]], 
 Triangle[{{0, 0}, r {Cos[ϕ], 0}, r {Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ]}}],
 Circle[{0, 0}, .1 r, {0, ϕ}],
 Text[Style["ϕ", 14, Italic], 
    .15 r {Cos[ϕ/2], Sin[ϕ/2]}],
 Text[Style["Power\n triangle"], 
    r {Cos[ϕ]/2, Sin[ϕ]/4}]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}},
  Axes -> True,
  ImageSize-> 600,
  AxesLabel -> {"P (Real Power)", "I (Apparent Power)"}],
 {{ϕ, .2}, 0, π/2},
 {{r, 1}, .5, 2}
 ]
```

Comment: Can you use my code and make it bigger, with your information?

Comment: You certainly have the start you requested.  I think you're on your own for the refinements.

Comment: @JanEerland You see? That was what I was referring to in my comments under your question. Mathematica is too vast and complex to try to find your way out of a problem with a simple hint and without spending a lot of _your_ time afterwards

Comment: Sure I see! The only thing I wanna know now is how to make that half Phi circle in my code: Show[Graphics[{FaceForm[RGBColor[0.586667, 2/3, 0.586667]], 
   Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]}, {Axes -> True, 
   PlotLabel -> HoldForm[Vermogensdriehoek], 
   LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}}], 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Re -> P = UICos[\[CurlyPhi]]], 
   HoldForm[Im -> Q = UISin[\[CurlyPhi]]]}, PlotLabel -> None]

Comment: But what you call the "half Phi circle" (actually, the *full* Phi arc) *is* implemented in my code, as you can surely see when you run it.